# Community Connector Settings

Tags: looker-studio

I'm building a community connector that uses Oauth2 as the authentication method. There are some settings that I have right now as Script properties.
Is there a way to show these settings on a community connector before the authentication flow is launched?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "show these settings"? Where do you want to show them?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify any UI element or trigger any event prior to the third-party authentication for a community connector. So, no, you cannot surface any information from Script Properties prior to the third-party OAuth2 flow.

However, you will have access to the Script Properties in your code. So you can pass the information to whatever endpoint you are connecting and surface that *during* the OAuth2 flow.

Comment: Thank you, so what happens in the case that for a partner connector something like the client ID or client secret vary by third party account? Is it valid to use NONE as auth method and request these values when setting up the connection?

Comment: One thing you can try is: First your `getAuthType` should return `KEY`. Then capture the key value from the user and store it in script properties. If that value exists in script properties, `getAuthType` should return `OAUTH2`. Then use your regular flow.